# Running multiple SQL statements in the one operation

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to use ADO to create several tables at once, into MS Access. Is it possible to do multiple statements in the one operation? For instance:

```
...
// I have omitted the field details 
CString sQuery = "CREATE TABLE [Table1] (..., PRIMARY KEY ([ID])); \nCREATE TABLE [Table2] (..., PRIMARY KEY ([ID]));";
oRecordset.Open(oDatabase.m_pConnection, sQuery)
```

This fails due to a `"Syntax Error in CREATE TABLE statement"`, although each of the create statements work on their own perfectly. Is there a way of doing this sort of thing? There will also be statements to add constraints, add indexing, etc., and I'd really like to be able to do it so that I don't have to split up the string into separate parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ADO to MS Access does not support batch SQL statements. You need to run each statement as a separate execution.

Answer (score 11):

ADO isn't the issue: the ACE/Jet engine simply does not support multiple SQL statements within a single operation. In other words, ACE/JET SQL lacks procedural syntax found in most 'industrial-strength' SQL products. See @David-W-Fenton's answer for more detail.

Bottom line: You will need to issue a `Connection.Execute` for each `CREATE TABLE` statement i.e. client side procedural code. But they can (perhaps should) all be run in the same transaction, of course.

Answer (score 2):

People who think you can send multiple SQL statements to Jet in a batch just aren't thinking.

Jet is a file-server database engine -- there is no centralized server process controlling interaction between clients and the actual data store. Instead, clients are all running individual instances of Jet and cooperatively editing a file in a way that is controlled by the Jet locking file (LDB). Without a centralized process to serialize and prioritize the SQL statements, you wouldn't *want* Jet to be able to process multiple statements in a batch.

Those who are offering the suggestion of using ADO and separating the statements with a CrLf should code it up and give it a try and then get back to us about how useful their speculative advice actually is.

Comment: Being *a file-server database engine* is not an explanation for not handling multiple statements at once. E.g., sqlite handles those quite well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sample set of commands is typical, just do something like this in VBA or the language of your choice:

> ```
> public sub ExeuteBatch(BatchString as String)
>     var s as string  
>     var abatch as array  
>     sbatch = replace(sbatch, "\n", "")
>     abatch = split(BatchString, ";")
>     for each s in abatch
>         ** adodb execute s here **
>     next s
> end sub
> ```

That's off the top of my head, but you should be able to take it from there I hope.

Answer (score 1):

Crude but it works - create the necessary number of queries with one SQL statement each, then use a Macro to run the queries successively. That's about as good as can be done with ADO/Jet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if ADO is constructed over JET OleDB Engine, which I suppose, if it is this way, The Jet Engine doesn't support execution of multiple statements in one single batch, we tryed separating with ; and with the GO reserved word, but it does not work.

Comment: ADO is not "constructed over the Jet OleDB Engine"--but the ADO *privider* for Jet is....

Answer (score 0):

I think you can run multiple commands in one ADO Command.

You just need proper line feeds between then. i.e. \n doesn't work.

Try something like this:
(Using VB Syntaxish)

```
MyQuery = "Select * from Whatever " & vbLf <br>
MyQuery = MyString & "Select * from SomethingElse " & vbLF

oRecordset.Open(oDatabase.m_pConnection, MyQuery )
```

Comment: ADO simply passes the SQL code to the engine and the engine in question (ACE/Jet) has no support for multiple SQL statements).

Comment: Ah, that would make sense.   Thinking about it, I have done this successfully on SQL Server.